# Format of date inserting wrong on database

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

This is my code for the date:

```
  DateTime datetry = DateTime.Now;
  lebeldet.Text = string.Format("{0:MMM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt}", datetry);
```

In label, its displaying the result that i wanted

[image]:

But when its inserted into the database and crystal report print it looked like this.

[image]

this is my code for insertion.

```
  crud.AddRecord("Update SalesTransaction Set Date = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(lebeldet.Text) + "' , Cashier = '" + cashier.Text + "', TotalSales = '" + totaldue.Text + "' , SubTotal = '" + subtotal.Text + "' , Discount = '" + discount.Text + "'  , DiscountableSales = '" + totaldiscountablesales.Text + "'  , Vat = '" + totalvat.Text + "'  , VatableSales = '" + totalvatablesales.Text + "'   where TransactionID = '" + salestransaction.TransactionID+"'  ");
```

How can i make the date to be inserted like "Aug/03/2017 12:30AM" ?

Comment: `datetime` values do not have an inherent format in a database (or any software, really). It all depends on the presentation-layer.

Comment: Oh so i cant change it sir? Should i change the type in database from datetime to varchar?

Comment: No. Don't do that!

Comment: @MattJohnson okay sir i guess its bad for the database. I really want it to look like that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when its inserted into the database and crystal report print it looked like...

A `datetime` value in a database, or a `DateTime` value in C#, do *not* have any format.  They represent a value.  You'll see a string in a particular format when you evaluate it, such as with the `ToString` method.

In a presentation tool, such as when you view the string in a table in SQL Management Studio, or in the Visual Studio debugger, there is an implicit call to `ToString` (or similar) occurring such that you can see the data.  The format of that is specific to the tool being used.  It is NOT part of the data itself.

For Crystal Reports and other reporting tools, you'll usually find a separate field or function to control the format displayed in the report.  You do this on the field in the report design, not on the data in the database.

Comment: Thank you sir i managed to changed it in crystal report field thanks!